Android ConstraintLayout the TextView boundary beyond constraint
I am using ConstraintLayout to do an android app page.
Here is my code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".test2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_image"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




I got this result:

But I want the text be constrainted by the left image's right boundary, and right image's left boundary. How to solve this unexpected result?

Have you checked my answer ?

@BobSmith yeah, use android:layout_width="0dp" exactly solved this problem. Thank you very much.

This is due to oversize TextView and right_image ImageView where the total width may be more than the screen width hence pushing the right_image out of the screen.

So you can add constraints that prevent the TextView from extending from the two ImageViews to take more space than is available and set width as 0dp.


ConstraintLayout features several attributes as below:

layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf : Align end of view to start of another
layout_constraintStart_toEndOf : Align start of view to end of another
layout_constraintTop_toTopOf : Align top of view to top of another


Others :

layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf : Align top of view to bottom of another
layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf : Align bottom of view to top of another
layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf : Align bottom of view to bottom of another
layout_constraintStart_toTopOf : Align start of view to top of another
layout_constraintStart_toBottomOf : Align start of view to bottom of another
layout_constraintStart_toStartOf : Align start of view to start of another
layout_constraintEnd_toTopOf : Align end of view to top of another
layout_constraintEnd_toBottomOf : Align end of view to bottom of another
layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf : Align end of view to end of another


Try this xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".test2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_image"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/left_image"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/left_image" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Output :

Reference link :

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#use-autoconnect-and-infer-constraints

https://proandroiddev.com/android-constraintlayout-explained-using-a-complex-ui-f4bc23998cab

https://constraintlayout.com/layouts/relativelayout.html



If we use wrap_content for the width or height of a view in a constraints layout It will always expand according to the content. To fill the width or height of a view between the constraints, the value should be set to 0dp.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".test2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_image"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right_image" />

use 0dp instead of wrap_content
